# Poritive orthant and positive functional

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $A$ be a hyperplane of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and denote by $\mathbb{R}_+^n$ the positive orthant, i.e. 
$$ \mathbb{R}_+^n = \{ v \in \mathbb{R}^n \;\mid\; v_i\geq0 \quad \forall i = 1 \dots n \} $$

Suppose $A \cap \mathbb{R}_+^n = \{0\}$.

Can we then say that there always exists a vector $c$ s.t. $c \perp A$ and $c\cdot v > 0$ for every $v\in \mathbb{R}_+^n \setminus \{0\}$ ?

My intuition (and the $n=2,3$ cases) suggests this is the case. But how to prove it formally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the hyperplane
$$A:x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=0$$
The intersection of $A$ and the orthant is $\{0\}$, since if some $x_j$ is positive, there must be some other $x_k$ which is negative.

A vector normal to this hyperplane is $c=(1,1,\ldots,1)$. For every $v\neq 0$ in the orthant
$$c\cdot v=v_1+v_2+\cdots+v_n>0$$

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed enough to pick the right basis to see it immediately. Btw I edited my question and your answer so that everything makes sense now!